# How to Setup base Authentication on the Website?

Tags: web

I have a Drupal Website Deployed on Linux Server, It doesn't have any base authentication, How can i setup this. It is. For Example, If somebody visit the site, It needs to input credentials to visit site.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a backend if you want a complex register/login system. Drupal documentation has a recomendation ([link](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2012-11-23/login-system))